# GoDaddy activation button missing in email?

Tags: dns, server

GoDaddy has sent a email to verify the domain name. however, they ask me to click a button to active. interestingly there is no activation button in my email.

I don't know what should i do now. Any type of help will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I changed the browser then button appeared. You can change your browser or mail services.

I used Google Chrome version 53.0.2785.143 with gmail account and button did not appear for 5 mail too then I used my android mobile phone with Chrome v49.0.2623.105 with gmail app then button appeared so I could verify email.